# find an inverse log transformation of an image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, transformation, imagefilter

I have been searching for this almost all day. The general form of the log transformation is

```
s = clog(1+r)
```

where

```
c = 0.1
```

The opposite is inverse log transformation(book). What will be the inverse log transformation? Is it

`s = exp(r)`?

Could not get right output.

Answer (score 6):

`Exp()` will only be an inverse of `Log()` if `Log()` is the [natural logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm). If your `Log()` is using a different base (base 2, base 10, any other arbitrary base), then you will need to use the different base in place of `e` in `Exp()`.

**Update**

Try `10^(x/0.1)-1`. `x/0.1` undoes the `0.1 *` operation, `10^` undoes the `log()`, and `-1` undoes the `+1`.

Comment: using the default base of 10.

Comment: +1 *I think its more readable if you use `0.1` instead of `.1`*

Comment: `log` in MATLAB is the natural logarithm. `10^` is wrong, use `exp` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think you defined `c` to normalize the resulting image to a valid (visible) range. Then a rational value for `c` could be:

```
c = (L - 1)/log(L)
```

where `L` is the number of gray levels. So `s` would be:

```
s = log(r+1) .* ((L – 1)/log(L))
```

or

```
s = log(r+1) .* c
```

Then the inverted transformation would be:

```
s2 = (exp(r) .^ (log(L) / (L-1))) – 1
```

or

```
s2 = (exp(r) .^ (1/c)) – 1
```

This is the transformation output for `L=256`:

[image]

To apply this transformation to an image we need to do some typecasting:

```
figure;
L = 256;
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
log_I = uint8(log(double(I)+1) .* ((L - 1)/log(L)));
exp_I = uint8((exp(double(I)) .^ (log(L) / (L-1))) - 1);
subplot(2, 2, [1 2]); imshow(I); title('Input');
subplot(2, 2, 3); imshow(log_I); title('\itlog(I)');
subplot(2, 2, 4); imshow(exp_I); title('\itexp(I)');
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use power law transform to do this as in power law transform you can shift the curve so as to perform log transform or to perform inverse log transform which effects high level pixels but not low level pixels..You may use this

```
a=imread('Figure-3.tif');
a=im2double(a);
[r,c]=size(a);
gamma=0.6;
C=1;
for i=1:r
for j=1:c
   s(i,j)=C*(a(i,j)^gamma);
end
end
imshow(s);
```

Comment: rolling back my edits again of your self-promotional, non-disclosed, unrelated links will cause your posts to be handled as spam. Just a friendly notice.

Answer (score -1):

This works for inverse log transformation

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
a=imread('imagename.jpg');
ad=im2double(a);
x=ad;
[r,c]=size(ad);
factor=1;
for i=1:r
    for j = 1:c
  x(i,j)= exp(ad(i,j)^factor)-1;
    end
end
subplot(1,2,1);imshow(ad);title('before');
subplot(1,2,2);imshow(x);title('after');
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
# Open the image.
img = cv2.imread('InverseLogTransform.jpg')
cv2.imshow('Input',img)
# Apply log transform.
c = 255 / (np.log(1 + np.max(img)))
ilog_transformed = np.(exp(img/c))-1
# Specify the data type.
ilog_transformed = np.array(ilog_transformed, dtype=np.uint8) 
cv2.imshow('ILog',ilog_transformed)
cv2.waitKey(0)cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```